# Can not define struct type: member name not declared

Tags: c++, struct

I try to define a struct type in C++ in the following way:

```
struct fckxMsg_t {   
unsigned char     : status;
unsigned char     : data1;
unsigned char     : data2;
};
```

My compiler complains with:

`error: 'status' was not declared in this scope unsigned char     : status;`

I don't see what is wrong. Actually I just want to give the members a name. Why should it have been declared before???

Comment: Variable declarations don't have a colon in them

Comment: What you are trying to do? Just define those structure members?

Comment: Oops,  I see that the first part of the definition is not in my post. It reads:  struct myStruct{

Comment: OK, I see. It is the colons inside the definition.....    Thanks!

Comment: I suspect that you're confusing C++ with some other language and would benefit from [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: You are right about confusing. The problem is in the fact that for my project I have to switch between multiple platforms/languages all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your quick response!

The correct code should be:

```
struct myStruct {
    unsigned char   status;
    unsigned char   data1;
    unsigned char   data2;
};
```

I can now jump to my next bug :-))